# selecting pandas rows: why isin() and not i in mylist?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a multi-index and need to select only the rows where the first index is not in a list. This works:

```
df= df.iloc[~(df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(mylist) )
```

This doesn't:

```
df= df.iloc[(df.index.get_level_values(0) not in mylist )
```

I get an error about the truth value of the array.

Why? What does it mean? Is it documented in the official docs?

Comment: You've missed a `]` off the end of the second example.

Comment: Thanks, hut that's not why it doesn't work

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous Yes it is.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 No, it is most certainly not. I had made an error copying the line from my script to this website, but if I run it with the proper ] I still get this error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 you can try it yourself with this simple example: 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

consdf=pd.DataFrame()

for mylocation in ['North','South']:
    for scenario in np.arange(1,4):
        df= pd.DataFrame()
        df['mylocation'] = [mylocation]
        df['scenario']= [scenario]
        df['this'] = np.random.randint(10,100)
        df['that'] = df['this']  * 2
        df['something else']  = df['this'] * 3
        consdf=pd.concat((consdf, df ), axis=0, ignore_index=True)

Comment: and then:

mypiv = consdf.pivot('mylocation','scenario').transpose()

level_list =['this','that']

mypiv= mypiv.iloc[(mypiv.index.get_level_values(0) not in level_list )]

Answer (score 1):

Say, you have a dataframe df as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(30).reshape((6,5)))
tuples = [(i//2, i%2) for i in range(6)]
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
print(df)

        0           1           2           3           4
0   0   0.623671    0.335741    0.035219    0.902372    0.349697
    1   0.487387    0.325101    0.361753    0.935972    0.425735
1   0   0.147836    0.599608    0.888232    0.712804    0.604688
    1   0.156712    0.286682    0.680316    0.104996    0.389507
2   0   0.212923    0.580401    0.02415     0.712987    0.803497
    1   0.804538    0.035597    0.611101    0.328159    0.140793
```

`df.index.get_level_values(0)` will return an array: `Int64Index([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], dtype='int64')`

The error says that by using `in` operator it is not clear whether you want to check all elements in that array are in the list, or any element in that array is in the list. You are comparing the array against the whole list. What you want is the element-wise comparison and `in` does not do that. Even if it was clear, it would return a single value. If you try `df.index.get_level_values(0).isin([0,1])`, on the other hand, it will return an array of boolean values: `array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)` so it will check first whether 0 is in the list, whether second 0 is in the list, whether 1 is in the list... And then those boolean values will be used to slice the dataframe (i.e. show me only the rows where the array has `True` value).

```
In [12]: df.iloc[[ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False]]
Out [12]:       0   1           2           3           4
0   0   0.623671    0.335741    0.035219    0.902372    0.349697
    1   0.487387    0.325101    0.361753    0.935972    0.425735
1   0   0.147836    0.599608    0.888232    0.712804    0.604688
    1   0.156712    0.286682    0.680316    0.104996    0.389507
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful. I suppose my confusion also stems from my being used to SQL, where each condition is basically evaluated row-by-row. I'm finding it quite complicated to convert non-banal conditions from SQL to pandas.

Comment: PS In fact, a few times I found myself exporting pandas dataframes to a sqlite database in memory, running queries there, then exporting back to a dataframe